# Django Issue on Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am running the Django rest framework and it is running fine but > when It goes to docker then I see this issue. Is anyone knows how to resolve the issue?  I am searching on the internet but did not find any solution, anyone who encounters the same issue?

```
 Attaching to jdx_web_1
    web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    web_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    web_1  |     self.run()
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    web_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    web_1  |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    web_1  |     raise _exception[1]
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    web_1  |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    web_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    web_1  |     app_config.import_models()
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    web_1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
    web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    web_1  |   File "/code/home/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    web_1  |     from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
    web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 6, in <module>
    web_1  |     raise ImportError('win32 only')
    web_1  | ImportError: win32 only
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to import `asyncio.windows_events` who says `i'm for windows only` whilst the docker image I presume is not windows-based. Get rid of windows-only lib or build your image on windows OS.

Comment: I am building the image on windows which using 64 bit  architecture.

Comment: `using 64 bit` vs `ImportError: win32 only`